# I don't find the LU decomposition on the device with cuSolver

Tags: c++, c, cuda, determinants, cusolver

I need to calculate the determinant of a matrix (array of double) with cuda and I want use the LU decomposition to do this.
I don't find the device function in `cusolverSp.h` but only the host function `cusolverSpDcsrlsvluHost`. 
I look in cuda 7.0 and cuda 7.5.

I don't understand why I can't find it because it is described in the official documentation: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#api

Other functions like the Cholesky decomposition on the device works.

Is it implemented?
If yes, where can I find it?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the documentation you pointed I see:

> Remark 5: only CPU (Host) path is provided

A bit of reading on the page gives this:

> Next, cuSolverSP provides a new set of sparse routines based on a
>   sparse QR factorization. Not all matrices have a good sparsity pattern
>   for parallelism in factorization, so the cuSolverSP library also
>   provides a CPU path to handle those sequential-like matrices. For
>   those matrices with abundant parallelism, the GPU path will deliver
>   higher performance. The library is designed to be called from C and
>   C++.

Combining the two quotes, I guess the device function wasn't deemed worth providing... This is just my interpretation though.

Comment: Thank you, I don't read the remarks and it's an error to me. Remark 6: multithreaded csrlsvlu is not avaiable yet. 
It's clear. Thank you.